# Kendo Angular Grid does not displaying data from JSON response

Tags: json, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have following Kendo grid table:

```
<kendo-grid options="projectDetail.mainGridOptions">
                </kendo-grid>

      $scope.projectDetail.mainGridOptions = {
                    //data: data.results,
                    dataSource: {
                                data: data.results,
                                schema: {
                                    model: {
                                        fields: {
                                            name: { type: "string" }
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                pageSize: 20,
                                },
                    sortable: true,
                    height: 550,
                    pageable: true,
                    columns: [{
                        field: "name",
                        title: $translate.instant('NAME'),
                        width: "120px"
                        }
                    ]
                };
```

Problem is that date are not displayed in view.

JSON from response has following structure>

```
{
    "resultCount": 2,
    "results":
        [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Attribute1.5",    
                "defaultName": "attributeDefName1",                  
                "defaultPosition": 0,
                "dataType": "String"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Attribute2",    
                "defaultName": "attributeDefName2",                  
                "defaultPosition": 1,
                "dataType": "String"
            }
         ]
}
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  http://jsbin.com/huquvukara/1/edit?html,js,console,output  Is there anything in the console of the browser when you run this code ?

Comment: How do you load the data? Are you sure that when you initialize the Grid you already have the data available?

Comment: I'm loading data on success callback of the HTTP request. So i thing that it should works fine, but no it is not working althought values for scope are available in the view.  No error in console.

Comment: I found, that if i put configuration object outside of the function without async data it works. But what can i do when i would like to doisplay data from remote source? (It means from assync HTTP request) I tried to use $scope.apply but it does not work for me.